# Leaflet - Filtering GeoJSONs data using Selects values

Tags: select, leaflet, geojson

I have a bus network with 2 GeoJSONs : one for stations (points) and the other for lines between them.

I have 3 selects :first one to select the bus line and filter the stations on the other two that are for origin and destination stations.

What I want to do is to dynamically filter the bus lines on the first select and the bus stations on the last two selects.

Something like this : 
User selects L1 on first select > Map only shows Line 1 (both geojsons, points and lines) and hide the other Lines that were showing.
User selects Station x on select 2 and Station y on select 3 > Map only shows these stations and the ones in between (both geojsons, points and lines).

Stations GeoJSON (not complete) :

```
var station ={
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "test",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 0, "nom": "JAMAA EL FNA", "ligne": "L1", "ville": "MARRAKECH", "direction": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -7.991506070410076, 31.624380871588261 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 1, "nom": "KOUTOUBIA", "ligne": "L1", "ville": "MARRAKECH", "direction": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -7.993921192850516, 31.62551706188404 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 2, "nom": "HOTE DE VILLE", "ligne": "L1", "ville": "MARRAKECH", "direction": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -7.997800602958748, 31.627492814514493 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 3, "nom": "R.P BERDII", "ligne": "L1", "ville": "MARRAKECH", "direction": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -8.003733858117105, 31.630010280990067 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 4, "nom": "GRAND POSTE", "ligne": "L1", "ville": "MARRAKECH", "direction": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -8.009040991276375, 31.633004916540266 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 5, "nom": "CAREE EDEN", "ligne": "L1", "ville": "MARRAKECH", "direction": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -8.011327830139466, 31.634311225216251 ] } },....
```

Lines GeoJSON (not complete) :

```
var lignemarrakech = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "ligne",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 0, "ligne_bus": "L1", "direction": "A", "from_st": null, "to_st": null, "ville": "MARRAKECH" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -7.991506070410076, 31.624380871588261 ], [ -7.99177772113954, 31.62455510452893 ], [ -7.992132146977649, 31.624680377597475 ], [ -7.992359514496435, 31.624737319845583 ], [ -7.992653754814866, 31.624862592668791 ], [ -7.993295733691442, 31.625147303003317 ], [ -7.993583286729908, 31.625306740410121 ], [ -7.993921192850516, 31.62551706188404 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 1, "ligne_bus": "L1", "direction": "A", "from_st": null, "to_st": null, "ville": "MARRAKECH" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -7.993929771507931, 31.625520494421043 ], [ -7.993921192850516, 31.62551706188404 ], [ -7.994251765813826, 31.625734485234361 ], [ -7.994613027718003, 31.625968537122866 ], [ -7.994699416434219, 31.626022034614714 ], [ -7.995311990967388, 31.626396516196305 ], [ -7.995618278233972, 31.626550320694935 ], [ -7.995971686618494, 31.626730873477591 ], [ -7.99655284707304, 31.627018419778416 ], [ -7.997188982165176, 31.627279216817595 ], [ -7.997597365187289, 31.627433019856959 ], [ -7.997800602958748, 31.627492814514493 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 2, "ligne_bus": "L1", "direction": "A", "from_st": null, "to_st": null, "ville": "MARRAKECH" }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ -7.997800602958748, 31.627492814514493 ], [ -7.998131404523898, 31.627586822642048 ], [ -7.998704711458787, 31.62774731223368 ], [ -7.999246604315053, 31.627847618087841 ], [ -7.999898446446502, 31.627981359058502 ], [ -8.000487460420704, 31.628188657183067 ], [ -8.001194277189745, 31.628529695028082 ], [ -8.001987482675004, 31.628984410209988 ], [ -8.00258435016886, 31.629345505977 ], [ -8.002796395199573, 31.629499305600273 ], [ -8.002835662797853, 31.629606296492579 ], [ -8.002859223356822, 31.629659791892589 ], [ -8.002906344474757, 31.629686539581062 ], [ -8.002984879671317, 31.629726661099347 ], [ -8.00307912190719, 31.629733348017368 ], [ -8.003181217662718, 31.629726661099347 ], [ -8.003401116213087, 31.629820277908031 ], [ -8.003733858117105, 31.630010280990067 ] ] } },...
```

This is what I could do for the first select :

```
                $('#selectLine').on('change', function() {
                  console.log("chosen_line= " + this.value);
                  chosen_line = this.value;
                  filterLines();

                    if (chosen_line= 'L1'){
                    L.geoJSON(lignemarrakech, {
                    filter: function(feature, layer) {
                    return feature.properties.ligne='L1';
                    }
                    }).addTo(mymap);
                    }
                    else{
                      }
                });
```

Beside the fact that it's not generalised, it doesn't work as intended (show only L1 when L1 is selected), it just display all the lines again on top.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (chosen_line= 'L1')
```

should be

```
if (chosen_line == 'L1')
```